# Changing datatype of a column, which is referenced by other tables

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I want to change the datatype of a primary key column in Table A, which is referenced by Table B. The schema is something like-

Table A: (col1A number, col2A...)
Table B: (col1B number, col2B...)

col2B -> col1A

I want to change datatype of col1A from number to varchar. I want that to reflect in Table B also. Is there any simple way to do that?

--
Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

No, there is no simple way to do this.  Assuming that both tables have data in them, you'd need to

- Add a new `VARCHAR2` column to table A
- Update A to set the new column equal to `TO_CHAR( col1A )`
- Add a new 'VARCHAR2` column to table B
- Update B to set the column equal to `TO_CHAR( col2B )`
- Drop the existing foreign key constraint
- Drop the existing primary key constraint
- Drop `col1A` from A
- Drop `col2B` from B
- Rename the new columns (if desired) in A & B to `col1A` and `col2B`
- Create the new primary key constraint
- Create the new foreign key constraint

Obviously, that's going to be a rather expensive operation.

Answer (score 1):

This is a proof of concept in T-SQL (SQL Server). Basically, we're changing the primary key's data type from `INT` to `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` (GUID) in table `A`, which is referenced by a foreign key in table `B`.

```
-- ARRANGE

CREATE TABLE A(
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_A PRIMARY KEY (Id)
)

CREATE TABLE B(
    [Id] INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [A_Id] INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_B PRIMARY KEY (Id),
    CONSTRAINT FK_B_A FOREIGN KEY (A_Id) REFERENCES A(Id)
)

INSERT A DEFAULT VALUES

DECLARE @A_Id INT
SELECT @A_Id = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

INSERT INTO B VALUES (@A_Id)
INSERT INTO B VALUES (@A_Id)
INSERT INTO B VALUES (@A_Id)
INSERT INTO B VALUES (@A_Id)
INSERT INTO B VALUES (@A_Id)

-- ACT

ALTER TABLE A ADD New_Id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL DEFAULT NEWID() 
ALTER TABLE B ADD New_A_Id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NULL
UPDATE B SET B.New_A_Id = (SELECT A.New_Id FROM A WHERE A.Id = B.A_Id)

ALTER TABLE B DROP FK_B_A
ALTER TABLE B DROP COLUMN A_Id
EXEC sp_RENAME 'B.New_A_Id', 'A_Id', 'COLUMN'

ALTER TABLE A DROP PK_A
ALTER TABLE A DROP COLUMN Id
ALTER TABLE A ADD CONSTRAINT PK_A PRIMARY KEY (New_Id)
EXEC sp_RENAME 'A.New_Id', 'Id', 'COLUMN'

ALTER TABLE B ADD CONSTRAINT FK_B_A FOREIGN KEY (A_Id) REFERENCES A(Id)

-- ASSERT

SELECT * FROM A
SELECt * FROM B
```