# Changing keys and data for Azure Mobile Service

Tags: sql-server, azure, mobile

I have an existing Azure web application backed by an Azure SQL db. My plan is to utilize this same db in new mobile applications I am building, however I made a design decision originally that doesn't work with Azure Mobile Services. I made my keys in the existing database integer ID's and as of recently to utilize a db within the Mobile service it needs ID's that are String GUID's. I have over 200 users entered in my existing database with other associated tables all tied to these ID's.

My question is, is there a feature or methodology for converting all of these integer keys to string keys without dropping all of their data and requiring everyone to manually go in and re set things up again?
My database knowledge is limited but from all I've seen, Azure Mobile Service requires that the keys be strings now and there isn't a work around for it.

Any help is much appreciated, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To change the datatype of a column in SQL, just simply run the following command:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
ALTER COLUMN column_name column_type
```

For example, assume your table name is table1 and the column is called keys,

```
ALTER TABLE table1
ALTER COLUMN keys varchar(10)
```

Comment: I try and run this command however, it doesnt work because those keys are referenced by other tables in the schema. Is there a way to cascadingly apply this change?

Comment: @user3286257 So your situation is that table A has a primary key A, which is referenced by Table B as foreign key. You want to change A's data type and reflect in Table B, right? I don't think there is a simple way to do this. You'll need to add a new varchar column in both Table A and Table B, drop the original foreign key and primary key, then reset the refenence between the two new added keys, this obviously is not simple. Check this thread for details http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9023259/changing-datatype-of-a-column-which-is-referenced-by-other-tables